# SOQL - Field must be grouped or aggregated

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

This is a Trigger that will send an email when the same Account has 8 cases created in the last 5 days.  I am receiving a SOQL error:

> System.UnexpectedException: field 'Client_Advisor_Email__c' can not be grouped in a query call

However when I remove 'Client_Advisor_Email__c' from the search I receive a total opposite message:

> System.UnexpectedException: field 'Client_Advisor_Email__c' can not be grouped in a query call

This is a field I will need further into the code as you will see.  Any assistance is appreciated.

```
trigger CaseHandlerCountAlert on Case (after insert) {
    List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co,
                                    Project__r.Implementation_status__c, Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c
                                    FROM Case
                                    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 AND Id IN :Trigger.New
                                    GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                    HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 8];


                for(AggregateResult aggr:AggregateResultList){ 
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                            if(aggr != Null && Project__r.Implementation_status__c == 'LIVE - TRANSITION'){    
                                 //Set Outgoing Email to Implementation Coordinator
                                 message.toAddresses = new String[] { Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c }; 
                            }
                            else if (aggr != Null && Project__r.Implementation_status__c == 'Live - Closed Project'){  
                                 //Private method getAddresses() retrieves email address from Customer_Success_Managers Public Group

                                 message.toAddresses = new String[] { getAddresses() };
                            } 

                        message.Subject = 'Subject Test Message';
                        message.PlainTextBody = 'Account name: ' + aggr.get('name') + ' has ' + (Integer)aggr.get('co') + ' cases opened in the last 8 days.';
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
                        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
                    System.debug('Account Name: ' + aggr.get('name'));   
                }            

private List<String> getAddresses(){
    List<User> UserList =
            [SELECT id, name, email
            FROM User 
            WHERE id 
            IN (SELECT userorgroupid 
                FROM groupmember
                WHERE group.name = 'Customer Success Managers')];

    List<String> emailString = new List<String>();

    for(User u: UserList){
        emailstring.add(u.email);
    }   
    return (emailString);
    }    
}
```

Comment: There are a couple things that I don't know about your scenario. First, are you groupign by the Client_Advisor_Email__c field instead of Account.Name, or in tandem with it? Because they rest on different objects, so I don't know how that will affect the groupings. More importantly though, I don't know what kind of field it is (grouping only works on certain field types).

Comment: If you're just querying the field (not using it for the grouping), then it won't work because it isn't being grouped. What you will need is actually two queries then. After the first query, collect the Ids of all the Cases that are returned. Then do a second query on those Cases that grabs the fields that you needed. It all depends on what it is you're trying to accomplish. If you provide more detail, I can whip up an actual answer for you.

Comment: Thank you for responses so far.  I am having some difficulties creating the second SOQL search.  Anyone kind enough to share some code of what the second SOQL would look like?

Comment: One recommendation: move the `getAddresses()` method call out of the `AggregateResult` `for` loop. Queries in loops are bad practice.

Comment: @Roti I am not looking to group by Client_Advisor_Email__c.  Looks like I will need a second SOQL query for the Project__c object.  I am just not quite getting the syntax down or how to start the second query.

Comment: David just marked this as a duplicate of another question with an answer that shows what I was talking about. It shows how to use a second query. Hope that helps. As for the syntax, loop through the returned AggregateResults and get all the record Ids from all the Cases and store them in a Set. Then use that set in a second Case query like such: [SELECT Id, AccoundId, Account.Name, Project__r.Implementation_status__c, Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIdSet]; Replace caseIdSet with the name of the Set you used. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, for clarification, you can't get the Case Id form the AggregateResult. What you need to get is the AccountId. And use the AccountId in the Case query like "WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 AND Id IN :Trigger.New AND AccountId IN :accountIds". Then you will get all the recent Cases for those Accounts.